# SpringResourceTemplateResolver's setPrefix method does not set requested path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to have html files inside `webapp/WEB-INF/view` folder. Therefore I have created following config file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "base.package.name" })
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {".html"});

        return resolver;
    }

    private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());

        return engine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(true);

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

index.html for testing purposes is located in `resources/templates/index.html` and `webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.html`.

When I visit `localhost:8080` index.html is loaded from `resources/templates` instead of `webapp/WEB-INF/**`

I tried to delete index.html in resources folder but then I received FileNotFound exception.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Test this in `application.properties` file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway my problem persists and index file is taken from ```resources/templates/```